# mkdir with date function behaves differently in script

Tags: linux, date, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory with a timestamp. If I type at the prompt

```
mkdir "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)"
```

I get a directory named with the date as I would like. If I put the same line in a bash script I get some strange characters at the end of the name. What is going on?

Comment: you should ask your question in a Linux site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't reproduce it. When I put just that line in a bash script it worked fine.

Comment: I'm also creating the directory. Which shell are you using? It might be because of the shell.

Comment: I have tried bash and sh. I guess I should add that I am doing this in Windows using Cygwin